# Resume after suspend not always asks for password

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, password

Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS is freshly installed on my Acer Swift 314-57 laptop. When I enter suspend mode by selecting this on the upper right menu, then my password ***is not*** requested upon resume.  When I enter suspend mode by closing the lid/display, then my password ***is*** requested.

Where/how can I change the password requirement options?

Comment: Which way to want to change? Both require password or Neither require password?

Comment: Both requiring password would be best.

Comment: What I find hard to understand is that there can be two different behaviors for one event: wake up from suspend.